# Remove line-though comments in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writing API doc comments and would like to include code examples in a comment block with comments included in this same block. I have change the font color for the block comments themselves but not for the comments in the comment.

Is there a way to edit the colors/text-decorations of these? I find it too dark and difficult to read. This happens with every theme I have installed.

[image: line-through text example]

Comment: It would be nice to include code text in the question (in addition to screenshot).

Comment: Also, this decoration is most likely an extension fault.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to VS Code, you can highlight an example of the code usage using `JSDoc` tags. In your instance you're looking for `@example`:

```
/**
* @example
* myFunc('calling my func');
*/
function myFunc(args) {
}
```

And you will see your code sample highlighted in VS Code:

[image]